# Ruby: building a plot of function

Tags: ruby, function, plot

What's the easiest way to build a plot of a function under Ruby? Any suggestions as to the special graphical library?

**update:** under windows only :-(

**update 2:** found the following gem as a best solution so far https://github.com/clbustos/rubyvis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is [`gnuplot`](http://rgplot.rubyforge.org/) a possible option?:

```
require 'gnuplot.rb'
Gnuplot.open { |gp|
    Gnuplot::Plot.new( gp ) { |plot|
        plot.output "testgnu.pdf"
        plot.terminal "pdf colour size 27cm,19cm"

        plot.xrange "[-10:10]"
        plot.title  "Sin Wave Example"
        plot.ylabel "x"
        plot.xlabel "sin(x)"

        plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( "sin(x)" ) { |ds|
            ds.with = "lines"
            ds.linewidth = 4
        }
        plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( "cos(x)" ) { |ds|
            ds.with = "impulses"
            ds.linewidth = 4
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gnuplot is very sweet, but somehow I cannot get the examples running. Just installed the gem. Running 1.8.6 on Windows. Any ideas/required plugins?

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't obvious, but have you got gnuplot itself installed? The Ruby bit is only the bindings, AFAIK

Comment: In response to @Brent: here is the page to download gnuplot: http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else stumbles over this, I was able to use gnuplot using the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gnuplot' 

Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  Gnuplot::Plot.new( gp ) do |plot|

    plot.xrange "[-10:10]"
    plot.title  "Sin Wave Example"
    plot.ylabel "x"
    plot.xlabel "sin(x)"

    plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( "sin(x)" ) do |ds|
      ds.with = "lines"
      ds.linewidth = 4
    end
  end
end
```

Requiring rubygems and using the correct gem name for gnuplot was the key for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is my go-to graphing library: [SVG::Graph](http://www.germane-software.com/software/SVG/SVG::Graph/)

Comment: This one's the only worked for me. But - can I produce continuous function graph instead of just dotted?

Answer (score 0):

I really like [tioga](http://tioga.rubyforge.org/). It can produce incredibly high quality, publication-ready graphs in latex.

Comment: tioga is for POSIX OS Family only :-(

Comment: Actually, Tioga works on windows now, although probably the requirements for a MikTeX installation is painful.

Answer (score 0):

use [SVG::Graph::Line](http://www.germane-software.com/software/SVG/SVG::Graph/doc/classes/SVG/Graph/Line.html) like this:

```
require 'SVG/Graph/Line'

  fields = %w(Jan Feb Mar);
  data_sales_02 = [12, 45, 21]
  data_sales_03 = [15, 30, 40]

  graph = SVG::Graph::Line.new({
          :height => 500,
          :width => 300,
    :fields => fields,
  })

  graph.add_data({
          :data => data_sales_02,
    :title => 'Sales 2002',
  })

  graph.add_data({
          :data => data_sales_03,
    :title => 'Sales 2003',
  })

  print "Content-type: image/svg+xml\r\n\r\n";
  print graph.burn();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's Microsoft Excel.

If so, the [Ruby on Windows](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/) blog may be useful, as are questions [tagged win32ole and ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32ole+ruby).