# Plotting time series graphs in jRuby

Tags: graph, plot, jruby

What is the simplest plotting tool to use in order to plot time series graphs in jRuby? For the time being I only need it to graph data within, for example, arrays. I am looking for something almost as easy as Matlab's code which is...

```
plot(array)
```

I realise there are some options available for Ruby but I am unsure if its possible to get them working on JRuby.

Thanks!

Comment: Matlab includes a visual environment. A pure programming language does not. What will you view the graph in? A browser? An image viewer in your OS of choice?

Comment: Hi Mark, it doesn't really matter. Maybe it could just be an image file that opens up or a flash visualisation. I just want to be able to run the model and see the graph pop up so I can see if it's running correctly.

Comment: This is still vague. Are there any user interface requirements? How will you be getting the data in the arrays? Do you already have an application? Is it CLI or webapp or native app? If not, do you plan or envision it? What OS is it?

Comment: Hi Mark, ideally I suppose I would like to add some sort of plot(array) line to the end of the program, then when it executes a window or whatever pops up so I can take a look at the results. I'm doing this in Windows in Komodo Edit. The program is an economic model and ideally I'd like to plot the time series values stored in the arrays as a time series graph. Because I am tweaking and running the model constantly, I'd like some quick graphical output so I can check the effects of these changes on the various time series.

Comment: This is similar to [Ruby: building a plot of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561729/ruby-building-a-plot-of-function)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks I will check it out! I was unsure if the Ruby gems would work in JRuby.